# Sql Procedure Not Working

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Here is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDelManu(
    @manuName VARCHAR
)
AS BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tbProducts WHERE itemManu = @manuName
END
GO
```

Here I try executing the procedure, but nothing shows up.

```
EXEC spDelManu @manuName='EVGA'
```

But, if I run this query it will work and I get results. Why doesn't it work with the variable created in the proc?

```
SELECT * FROM tbProducts WHERE itemManu = 'EVGA'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*sigh*, always declare explcitly the length of your varchar:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDelManu(
    @manuName VARCHAR(10)
)
AS BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tbProducts WHERE itemManu = @manuName;
END
```

As it was, it defaulted to a length of 1

Comment: Something so little yet so vital. No compile errors, it was driving me mad. Thanks

Comment: It wouldn't error on compile @DylanSowtis because it defaulted to the value of 1 so as far as SQL Server was concerned it was valid.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a size for `varchar`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDelManu(
    @manuName VARCHAR
)
AS BEGIN
    select @manuName
END
GO

EXEC spDelManu @manuName='EVGA'
```

returns: `E`

[Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)